# Не получается вывести название города YMaps

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

вообщем-то подключая библиотеку и пытаюсь получить местоположение юзера, но не получается.

Сам код:

Вы из г.document.write(((YMaps.location.city)?(YMaps.location.city):'Москва'));? Подождите!

Пример страницы: https://womanshouz.ru/test.html

Answer (score 0):

Судя по возвращаемой ошибке (403) вы скорее всего заблокированы за нарушение ПС. Напишите на maps-api@support.yandex.ru